# Unable to build Allegro program with Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, allegro5

Trying to compile and run a simple Allegro program using Sublime Text 2 and SublimeClang. If I run `g++ '/path/to/project/main.cpp' -o '/path/to/project/main' -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib -lallegro` on the command line, it compiles fine.

### Contents of C++.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0)"]
        }
    ]
}
```

### The run fails and the output of Sublime Console is:

`Running bash -c g++ '/path/to/project/main.cpp' -o '/path/to/project/main' && '/path/to/project/main' -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib -lallegro`

It seems that Sublime is adding `&& '/path/to/project/main'`, even though the build settings don't specify to do that. What is causing Sublime to add this `&& '/path/to/project/main'`? And how do I remove it?

In the bigger picture - this means Allegro will be linked in all C++ projects even if the libraries aren't being used. Is there a way to add the Allegro flags globally on my system? Sorry, not usually a C++ dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue. I used backticks instead of the `$()` notation:

```
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0` && ./${file_base_name}"]
```

Notice I also added `&& ./${file_base_name}` - which runs the program too.